# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

how do I solve this integral ?

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x}\,dx$$

how to start ?

Comment: I think this problem is well-known and has already been answered in this page. Possible duplicate (?)

Answer (score 0):

This integral is usually evaluated using Leibniz's rule. A full evaluation of this integral can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral